# Rename variables in SAS using macros

Tags: loops, sas, sas-macro

I have a dataset which has last 12 months debit and credit turnover and average balance of the customers. the data looks something like this

| Accountid | Monthly_credit_turover1 || Monthly_credit_turover2 |average_bal_1| average_bal_2

**i want to replace the  1,2,3 upto 12 with the last 12 months. for example- average_bal_1 should correspond to average_bal_march and average_bal_2 should get replaced with average_bal_april. so for all the variables with 1 should correspond to march,2 with April and so on**

The code that I have written is

```
%macro renaming(i=, mon=);



data bands_macro;
set may_1;
 *this just renames one variable with the two input parameters;
turnover_&i.=sum(MonthlyCreditTurnover&i., MonthlyDebitTurnover&i.);
format tn_bands $50.;
if turnover_&i. le 0 then tn_bands="1. LE 0";
else if turnover_&i. gt 0 and turnover_&i. le 1000  then tn_bands="2. 0-1k";
else if turnover_&i. gt 1000 and turnover_&i. le 4000  then tn_bands="3. 1k-4k";
else if turnover_&i. gt 4000 and turnover_&i. le 10000  then tn_bands="4. 4k-10k";
else tn_bands="5. >10k";
format ab_bands $50.;
if averagebalance&i. =999999999999 or averagebalance&i. le 0 then ab_bands="1.LE 0";
else if averagebalance&i. gt 0 and averagebalance&i. le 1000  then ab_bands="2. 0-1k";
else if averagebalance&i. gt 1000 and averagebalance&i. le 5000  then ab_bands="3. 1k-5k";
else if averagebalance&i. gt 5000 and averagebalance&i. le 10000  then ab_bands="4. 5k-10k";
else if averagebalance&i. gt 10000 and averagebalance&i. le 25000  then ab_bands="5. 10k-25k";
else if averagebalance&i. gt 25000 and averagebalance&i. le 50000  then ab_bands="6. 25k-50k";
else ab_bands="7. >50k";
drop MonthlyCreditTurnover&i. MonthlyDebitTurnover&i.;
run;
%mend;
%renaming(i=1,mon=Mar21);
%renaming(i=2,mon=Feb21);
```

But unfortunately I am getting this warning when i am running this code-

> variable turnover2 cannot be rename as turover_april because turnover_april already exists. How do i make these changes in single dataset

Comment: Turn on the MPRINT option to see why the code the macro is generating causes that error.

Comment: How do you know that 1 should be renamed to March?  Why not January? Or August?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is a pretty good use of a simple in-data step macro.

```
data mydata;
  turnover1 = 1;
  turnover2 = 2;
run;

*give two parameters, the numeric value and the month to convert to;
%macro renaming(i=, mon=);
*this just renames one variable with the two input parameters;
rename turnover&i.= turnover_&mon.;
%mend;

data want;
  set mydata;
  *now call each of the macro iterations separately;
  %renaming(i=1,mon=mar)
  %renaming(i=2,mon=apr)
  ;   *just to make the highlighting work;
run;
```

It would be possible to come up with a better list of these, for sure though:

```
*dataset of the i=mon relationships, you can have this in excel or whatever;
 *and change it every month when the other stuff updates;
*you also may be able to "calculate" all of this?;
data renames;
  input i mon $;  
  datalines;
1 mar
2 apr
;;;;
run;

*pull that into a macro variable using PROC SQL SELECT INTO;
proc sql;
  select cats('%renaming(i=',i,',mon=',mon,')')
    into :renamelist separated by ' '
    from renames;
quit;


*now apply the rename list;
data want;
  set mydata;
  &renamelist.
  ;
run;
```

Comment: @Joe- When i am writing this code and running this on two months- when it runs the loop for the second time it just works on the last variable and not all the variables , I have mentioned in the loop.

Comment: @joe- i have edited the code - in order to show you what is happening in the final dataset- it is just working on the feb loop and not showing results for the previous ones

Comment: Not sure why you're commenting on my answer; I'm suggesting you do this very differently, and it doesn't sound like you're doing that.